# Ban IP using Iptables/Firewalld

Tags: debian, centos, iptables, firewalld

I was DDos Attacked by Chinese Great Firewall twice this year.

Now I download zone file from http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/ .I want to do these things:

1. If Someone from Anywhere wants to connect to my server's specific port,All can be come in.
2. If Someone from China wants to connect to my server's any other ports,All packets should be dropped.Anyone else from other country can connect to my server correctly.

How Can I do?

I use a Cloudflare CDN free plan, but I just want to do above things on my server.

Comment: This sounds like a Cloudflare question?

Comment: of course not.I just want to ban it on my server.NOT CLOUDFLARE

Comment: No need to shout. I only asked for clarification. You might be able to get started with http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm so sorry.I forget to turn off the upper letters,So lazy I am

Comment: But I want to allow the banned country to connect to specific port,How should i do?

Comment: Since you use cloudflare, I would only accept web connections that come from cloudflare.

Comment: cloudflare will transfer ddos trafffic to my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `iptables` it will return on the first matching rule. If you want to allow http for example and deny the other ports for China, ensure that the http allow rule comes first:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d myhost --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set china src -j DROP
```

Using the above statements you will need to create an `ipset` for china using:

```
ipset create china hash:net
while read line; do ipset add china $line; done < china.ipblock-file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block using Apache module then you can try this also :

```
MaxMindDBEnable On
MaxMindDBFile DB /path/to/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(CN|RU|DE|FR) BlockCountry
Deny from env=BlockCountry
```